# Can a trait give default implementation for *some* methods of a parent trait?

Tags: rust, traits

Suppose we have a basic trait and an advanced trait as follows:

```rust
pub trait BasicTrait {
    fn key_method(&self);


    fn other_method(&self);
}

pub trait AdvancedTrait: BasicTrait {
    fn key_method_with_argument(&self, parameter: u32);
}
```

Now, every time someone will implement `AdvancedTrait`, the most likely implementation of `BasicTrait::key_method(&self)` is calling `key_method_with_argument` with some default argument. How can I provide this default implementation (idiomatically) so that anyone implementing `AdvancedTrait` will (1) only need to implement `key_method_with_argument` and any other required methods from `BasicTrait`, and (2) *optionally* implement `key_method()` and override the default implementation, only if needed?

Related questions:

having an `impl` block as proposed in the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52418809/can-a-trait-give-a-default-implementation-for-the-method-of-a-trait-that-it-inhe) does not work since the code is expected to implement all other methods of `BasicTrait`.

Comment: What you're looking for is called _specialization_, and not available, at least in stable Rust and soundly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The feature you want is called [specialization](https://rust-lang.github.io/rfcs/1210-impl-specialization.html), and unfortunately it is nightly-only and [has known soundness holes](https://aturon.github.io/blog/2017/07/08/lifetime-dispatch/), so don't expect it to stabilize soon. However, here's how it looks like with it:

```rust
#![feature(specialization)]

pub trait BasicTrait {
    fn key_method(&self);

    fn other_method(&self);
}

pub trait AdvancedTrait: BasicTrait {
    fn key_method_with_argument(&self, parameter: u32);
}

default impl<T: AdvancedTrait> BasicTrait for T {
    default fn key_method(&self) {
        self.key_method_with_argument(12345);
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=8bab6e71033fc40ee7febb8555ba7c86).

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response with the playground!

Answer (score 5):

You can do it by explicitly duplicating the `BasicTrait` methods into `AdvancedTrait`, ask your users to *only* implement `AdvancedTrait`, and then do a blanket impl for anything implementing `AdvancedTrait` to also implement `BasicTrait`. It is probably advisable to give the duplicated methods a name indicating they are just for implementing `BasicTrait`, and to prevent ambiguous calls:

```rust
pub trait BasicTrait {
    fn key_method(&self);
    fn other_method(&self);
}

pub trait AdvancedTrait: BasicTrait {
    fn key_method_impl(&self) {
        self.key_method_with_argument(0)
    }
    fn other_method_impl(&self);


    fn key_method_with_argument(&self, parameter: u32);
}

impl<T: AdvancedTrait> BasicTrait for T {
    fn key_method(&self) {
        AdvancedTrait::key_method_impl(self)
    }
    
    fn other_method(&self) {
        AdvancedTrait::other_method_impl(self)
    }
}
```

You could also call `key_method_impl` `basic_key_method` instead, a bunch of naming options exist.