# Specialise function implementation for a struct implementation

Tags: struct, rust, implementation, specialization

I am implementing a struct with a generic bounded to a trait, but that implementation is desirable to feature functions that bound the generic even more. Below is the example:

```rust
struct A<T> {
   data: T
}

impl <T: AsRef<[u8]>> A<T> {
    fn test(&self, t: &T) {}
    fn more_bound<S: AsRef<[u8]> + PartialEq>(&self, t: &S) {
        self.test(t);  
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=36a0d26fb895938d1a641d1ba5baa275)

I cannot really use a specialization as I don't implement a trait. Neither would I like to define a trait.
Are there any other options except changing the signature of `test` to
`fn test(&self, t: &impl AsRef<[u8]>) {}`?
Because such an approach seems to defeat the purpose of generics (in this case).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can a trait give default implementation for \*some\* methods of a parent trait?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70186164/can-a-trait-give-default-implementation-for-some-methods-of-a-parent-trait)

Comment: Not entirely, my design goal is to not introduce traits (let alone the trait inheritance), but have specializations in `struct`'s `impl`.

Comment: Trait inheritance can be eliminated, but I didn't saw you don't use traits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The compiler throws an error because in `more_bound` you take an `S` and then pass it into `test`, which requires a `T`. The fact that `S` and `T` are both `AsRef<[u8]>` (and `T` is weaker than `S`) is irrelevant since those generics have to match a fixed, concrete type (you promised a `&T` but gave an `&S` - who knows what `&S` is).

You can simply split the `impl` into two parts:

```
impl<T: AsRef<[u8]>> A<T> {
    fn test(&self, t: &T) {}
}

impl<T: AsRef<[u8]> + PartialEq> A<T> {
    fn more_bound(&self, t: &T) {
        self.test(t);
    }
}
```

The second `impl` will only be applicable for a `T` that is `AsRef<[u8]> + PartialEq`. As this bound guarantees that this `T` is `AsRef<[u8]>`, the `more_bound` method can call `test`, defined in the first `impl`.

If your original goal was to allow `more_bound` to be called with different types, you'll have to do the type-conversion via `AsRef` yourself:

```
impl <T: AsRef<[u8]>> A<T> {
    // Notice `test`takes the target of `AsRef<[u8]>`
    fn test(&self, t: &[u8]) {}

    fn more_bound<S: AsRef<[u8]> + PartialEq>(&self, t: &S) {
        // `S` can be whatever we want, it never "meets" `T`.
        self.test(t.as_ref()); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow, so simple. Not sure why I did not try it myself!